# Combining two data frames in single ggplot with facet wrap with different factor names?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

Say I have a df1 (incidents) and a df2 (records).

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-09","2021-07-04","2021-07-05"), value = c(200, 250, 123, 400), machine=c('abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'abc4'),sprocket=c('boop', 'blip', 'blip', 'boop'))


df2 <- data.frame(date2 = c("2021-07-02","2021-07-03","2021-07-06","2021-07-08"), record=c('record1', 'record2', 'record3', 'record4'), robot = c('abc2', 'abc42', 'abc1', 'abc3'))
```

So I want to plot x = date and y = value by sprocket for df1. Then for df2, I want to OVERLAY the records by machine, regardless of sprocket, on the correct date and machine.

Im having trouble getting the machines to line up without renaming 'robot' to 'machine' for df2, but I feel like there should be a way of specifying 'robot' = 'machine' or something in the facet_wrap.

Here is more of what I'm actually working with:

```
p3 <-ggplot() + 
  geom_point(df1, mapping = aes(x = date, y = value, color = value> 1.5 | value< -1.5)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  facet_wrap(vars(machine),ncol=5)+
  facet_grid(sprocket~ machine) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5, linetype = "dashed",color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = -1.5, linetype = "dashed",color = "red")+
  theme_classic() + 
  ylim(-30, 30)+
    scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2021-07-01"), max(df1$date), by="3 months"), date_labels =  "%b") +
  xlab("1974") +
  ylab("% blahblah")+
  
#here's the records bit
  geom_segment(df2, mapping = aes(x=date2, xend=date2, y=-30, yend=30), linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(.~robot, ncol=5)
```

What I want to do is plot df2 on top of the existing df2 graph seamlessly without renaming variables. I was able to do this mostly by renaming 'robot' to 'machine' for df2 but I want to know how to do it without that. Im still missing retaining the sprocket facet_grid part:

[image: Desired graph]

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this without renaming the column.  Any particular reason why you cannot rename before plotting?

Comment: Just curious in case I wanted to do something similar in the future

Comment: In that case, I would honestly just put it into a function and then set `data = fix_dataframes(df1, df2, col1, col2)` or something like that.